# Descriptive statistical analysis

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have some data obtained from questionnaire. The question asks to perform a descriptive statistical analysis for the above data and hence interpret your results. What does it mean? Is it mean I have to find the mean median mode standard deviation variance?

Comment: You might create a frequency table and a graphical representation (histogram, box plot, pie chart...) or a scatter chart, depending on the data. This information describes the data and you can look for any outliers in the data (stuff that looks out of place). If there are any, you might suggest why. After that, you can work out means etc. These numbers are usually called summary statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting to do numerical and graphical descriptions of data
for each question, it is important to determine whether the answers to the question are nominal, ordinal, or essentially numerical.

NUMERICAL (numbers, perhaps intervals): Perhaps age, income, or commute distance
to work. Modal intervals should be obvious. It might be possible to estimate medians and ranges.
Depending on allowed answers, perhaps even means and standard deviations. Graphical display might be a bar chart, showing
the relative frequency of each interval.

ORDINAL:  Answers like 'Strongly disagree/ disagree/ neutral/
agree/ strongly agree' or 'Never/ rarely/ occasionally/ often'.
You should be able to find mode and median. Bar chart (with
spaces separating bars) to make it clear you are not
representing a continuous scale.

NOMINAL: Answers like 'Male/Female' or 'Catholic/ Protestant/
Jewish/ Muslim/ Hindu/ Buddist/ Other'. Categories have no
natural order. Mode is the only valid measure of centrality.
Pie chart or bar chart.

Here is a summary of which measures of centrality you can
use of which data types.

```
 Valid Measures of Centrality for Various Data Types

           Nominal      Ordinal      Numerical
 Mean                  (See Note)       OK
 Median                    OK           OK
 Mode        OK            OK           OK
```

Computing the mean required addition and division, these arithmetic
procedures are only appropriate for numerical data. Finding the
median requires sorting and picking the 'middle' value. Ordinal
and numerical data can be sorted, Nominal cannot.

Note: Grades are inherently ordinal. Educational institutions
customarily assign arbitrary numerical values to these, such as A = 4, B = 3,
and so on. Then these numerical values are averaged to get a GPA
for each student. (Are two C's really the same as an A and an F?)
For large datasets the mean is a lot easier to find than the median.
This practice of grade points originated in an era when it was
feasible to compute GPAs, but not grade medians for large numbers
of students. It is relatively easy to find the median of a dozen numbers, but sorting a thousand as a prelude to finding the
median requires some computing power--power which is now routinely available. Even so, don't expect GPAs to disappear anytime soon.

'Likert' scaeles widely used in psychology and other social
sciences are another (often problematic) kind of attempt to treat
essentially ordinal data as numerical. (Can you meaningfully add
'Strongly opposed' and 'Favor'?)